# How do we prove that these series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, elliptic-functions

I found some interesting series
,for some examples
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( \tanh \left( \left( 2n+1 \right) \pi \right) \right)}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( \sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}} \right) 
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( \sinh \left( 2n+1 \right) \pi \right)}=\frac{\mathrm{arc}\cos \left( 3-2\sqrt{2} \right)}{2}
$$
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( \frac{\sinh \left( n\pi \right) -i\cosh \left( n\pi \right)}{\sqrt{2}} \right)}=-\mathrm{arc}\cos \left( \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \right) 
$$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( \left( \sqrt{2}-1 \right) \tanh \left( \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \sqrt{3}\pi \right) \right)}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( \frac{\left( 2+\sqrt{3} \right) ^{\frac{3}{8}}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\left( \sqrt{2\left( \sqrt{\sqrt{3}+2}+2 \right)}+2 \right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+2}+2}-\sqrt[4]{\sqrt{3}+2}}}} \right) 
$$
How do we prove that they converge,are these new results？

Comment: Note Latex has built-in commands like `\arctan` which provides the recommended spacing: $\arctan t$.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one doesn't seem to converge.

The tanh term tends to 1,
so the arctan tends to
$\pi/4$.

According to Wolfram Alpha,
the sum up to odd $n$
tends to about
-0.00186743404
and the sum up to even $n$
tends to about
0.7835307293489.

I think the same holds for the
other sums.

Comment: I also realized,These results should be defined as the values of the divergent sum.

Comment: "values of divergent sum" should be defined when you ask about it.